# How to query records for consecutive sequence of numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server

See this table:

Table name: A

```
Call Session ID           Sequence No       Source Application
STUD-213                     1              Application A
STUD-213                     2              Application B
STUD-213                     3              Application A
STUD-213                     4              Application C
STUD-321                     1              Application A
STUD-321                     2              Application C
STUD-321                     3              Application A
STUD-321                     4              Application B
```

This is a sample data. The problem is, I need to count the number of items in between these items. For example, how many ***Application A*** go to ***Application B***? My desired output should be:

```
Source Application      End Application         Count
Application A           Application B            7
Application B           Application C            10
Application A           Application C            6
```

I'm thinking this will be tricky if I will try this in SQL. The record for table A will be huge, around 10 million per month, so I'm also considering about the performance.

Do you have any suggestion on what to do with the querying of this?

**EDIT:** Changed the post title. Hope it helps someone who will stumble on this problem in the future.

Comment: What does 'from A to B' mean? Consecutive sequence numbers or first sequence is A and last sequence for session ID is B?

Comment: So basically you need a list of alll possible combations, so a carthesian product of all application-types and how often they are in one row and the next(acc. to  Sequence No and in the same `Call Session ID`-group)?

Comment: @BerndLinde - 'from A to B' means the consecutive sequence numbers.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - 'how often they are in one row and the next' exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CountApp is a count of how many times AppA ends up as AppB,
VersionCount is how many steps it took to get from AppA to AppB.

Hopefully one of these is what you are after.

```
declare @CS table (CallSessionID varchar(8), SequenceNo int, SourceApplication varchar(15))
insert into @CS
values
    ('STUD-213',1,'Application A'),
    ('STUD-213',2,'Application B'),
    ('STUD-213',3,'Application A'),
    ('STUD-213',4,'Application C'),
    ('STUD-321',1,'Application A'),
    ('STUD-321',2,'Application C'),
    ('STUD-321',3,'Application A'),
    ('STUD-321',4,'Application B')

select 
    mini.SourceApplication as StartApp, 
    maxi.SourceApplication as EndApp, 
    Count(*) as CountApp,
    mm.VersionCount
from
    (select CallSessionID, min(SequenceNo) MinSeq, Max(SequenceNo) MaxSeq, count(SequenceNo) VersionCount
    from @CS
    group by CallSessionID) mm
    inner join @CS mini
        on mini.CallSessionID = mm.CallSessionID
        and mini.SequenceNo = mm.MinSeq
    inner join @CS maxi
        on maxi.CallSessionID = mm.CallSessionID
        and maxi.SequenceNo = mm.MaxSeq
group by 
    mini.SourceApplication, 
    maxi.SourceApplication
```

**EDIT** Version 2
This version looks at the transition from one app to the next in the sequence and then does a count on each time it transition from AppA to AppB.

```
select  
    c1.SourceApplication as StartApp, 
    c2.SourceApplication as EndApp, 
    Count(*) as CountApp
from
    @CS c1
    inner join @CS c2
        on c1.CallSessionID = c2.CallSessionID
        and c1.SequenceNo = (c2.SequenceNo - 1)
group by
    c1.SourceApplication, 
    c2.SourceApplication
```

Comment: this results to only the first application and to the end application, what i need is the volume per sequence (how many for A -> B, B -> C, etc.).

but i think this one's near. i'll debug it for a while and maybe i can mark it as an answer if it's near to what i need.

Comment: @DustineTheGreat - I have added another solution for you to consider based on your comments.

Comment: @G B - great! the edit is good, and it's much faster than my solution. i think i over engineered about the solution and found it funny that it could be as simple as this. your query runs much faster (3 seconds) against 2 million records vs. my query 2.5 seconds). thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ended up solving my problem. I used a loop to get to each flow. Still not sure the performance of this once in production. I tried querying it against a table with 2.5 million records in 2.05 seconds.

I'll just leave this here to help anyone who wanders to this problem in the future:

```
DECLARE @MAXSEQNO INT
            , @MINSEQNO INT
            , @INCREMENT INT;

DECLARE @TABLE TABLE ([SourceApplication] VARCHAR(50)
                                        , [EndApplication] VARCHAR(50)
                                        , [ApplicationCount] INT);

SET @MAXSEQNO = (SELECT MAX(SequenceNo) FROM A)
SET @MINSEQNO = (SELECT MIN(SequenceNo) FROM A)

WHILE(@MINSEQNO <> @MAXSEQNO)
BEGIN

    SET @INCREMENT = (SELECT @MINSEQNO + 1)

    INSERT INTO @TABLE
                ([Sourceapplication], [EndApplication], [ApplicationCount])
    SELECT A.SourceApplication AS [StartApplication]
                , B.SourceApplication AS [EndApplication]
                , COUNT(*) AS [ApplicationCount]
    FROM A AS Main
    INNER JOIN A B ON (Main.CallSessionID = B.CallSessionID)
    WHERE A.ApplicationSequenceNo = @MINSEQNO
                AND B.ApplicationSequenceNo = @INCREMENT
    GROUP BY A.SourceApplication
                , B.SourceApplication

    SET @MINSEQNO = (SELECT @MINSEQNO + 1)

END

SELECT [SourceApplication]
            , [EndApplication]
            , SUM(ApplicationCount) AS [ApplicationCount]
FROM @TABLE
GROUP BY [SourceApplication]
                , [EndApplication]
```